# communication between two networks of sensors

Tags: simulation, contiki

I'm beginner in `contiki` in `cooja`. I want to simulate two networks. each networks has some sensor nodes and a sink node. Sensor's firmware is same but only for example sensors of one network sense temperature and another sense acceleration. The networks communicate with other through their sink node. I want to use examples in `contiki os`. It's not important what protocol is used. My object is only simulation and I want to understand code of example. I check `udp-sink.c` and `udp-sender.c` in `examples/ipv6/rpl-collect` path for my work. I want to use simple example. What a suggestion for source code of nodes and what reference is there for understanding of `contiki` codes?

Comment: Do you know how to communicate between a single network and the Internet? The same settings will work communication between two networks.

Comment: You mean i use border router? and for sensor nodes what program i can compile?

Comment: SO is not for resource recommendations, but this might be helpful: http://wireless.ictp.it/school_2016/book/IoT_in_five_days-v1.0.pdf

Comment: Yes, you'll need border router. I assume each network will have it's own - it wounds like that is your case. `rpl-border-router` will do the job. Once again, this question is a bad fit for SO as you mention some names of files but don't mention any specific problems of what happens when you use them.

Comment: I don't want use of real hardware. Is possible have two type of nodes, for example one sensing temperature virtually and another acceleration or light, etc. I mean, there isn't any real physical sensor but i just want to simulate two type of sensor.

Comment: Yes. What is your question?